# uGet Download Manager Problem in Chrome

Tags: apt, 20.04, google-chrome, uget

Are you using the uGet download manager for downloading any file, movie, video, zip, etc. from Google Chrome? When we click on download any files from different sites, the file starts downloading using Google Chrome's default download manager, but the file link doesn't open on the uGet download manager.

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy of the text that was in the question previously that is reposted as an answer.

If you're facing the same issues then do follow my steps!

- Open Chrome Web Store and search for uget [uGet Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVJ9u.png)
- After adding this extension you must enable it. You can see this picture.

  [image: uget extension]
- Go to this [link](https://github.com/ugetdm/uget-integrator/wiki/Installation), then open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uget-team/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install uget-integrator
```

After following these steps open Google Chrome, then open *Extensions* -> *Manage extensions* -> *uGet integration details* -> enable *Allow access to file URLs*

Comment: This seems to be a copy of the text that was in the question previously. If that's the case, it should be attributed to the OP (preferably they should be posting themselves)

Answer (score 0):

### uGet Download Manager in Ubuntu

uGet for Ubuntu is available from Ubuntu Software.

You can install it in the normal way.